# Can a RGH/JTAG Xbox 360 Console link to LAN Games on my Local Network?

Tags: xbox-360, mods, xbox-system-link

I am planning to RGH/JTAG my Phat Xbox 360 to play my backup games I made long ago.

What I want to know is, if an "official" Xbox 360 (i.e Non-RGH/JTAG) was to host a LAN Server for a game, say Black Ops 2, would this modded console be able to connect, with a **LEGIT** copy of the game (not a backup), to the LAN Server? Or will the server deny the console entry, since it is modded?

I cannot find any concrete information online, hence asking the question here.

Thanks again

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Yes, it will work. The retail console will connect to the RGH console.

Comment: Kind late, but why all the hate for this answer?